# toggle with hover/click and fade transition

Tags: jquery, fadein

I'm trying to make a menu that fadeIn/Out transition When click or hover image for the toggle.
I couldn't use css3 transition effect because for IE old version(7,8).

I'm newbie in Jquery, so can anyone help me please?

Here is the Code..

```
<div class="tab1">
    <ul>
        <li class="m1"><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
        <li class="m2"><a href="#">menu2</a></li>  
        <li class="m3"><a href="#">menu2</a></li>  
    </ul>
</div> 


.tab1 {position:relative; overflow:hidden; }
.tab1 li { display:inline-block; margin-right:10px;} 
.tab1 li.m1 a { display:block; background:red; width:100px; height:100px;  text-align:center; color:#fff; }
.tab1 li.m1:hover a, .tab1 li.m1.on a { background:pink;}
.tab1 li.m2 a { display:block; background:blue; width:100px; height:100px;  text-align:center; color:#fff; }
.tab1 li.m2:hover a, .tab1 li.m2.on a { background:skyblue;}
.tab1 li.m3 a { display:block; background:green; width:100px; height:100px;  text-align:center; color:#fff; }
.tab1 li.m3:hover a, .tab1 li.m3.on a { background:lightgreen;}

$('.tab1 li a').on('click', function(e){
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('on').siblings('.on').removeClass('on');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Here is the Demo

http://fiddle.jshell.net/9L7Dh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is jQuery UI [ToggleClass](http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/), addClass and removeClass functions, which accept time it takes to fade (in milliseconds) as the second parameter. For some reason I couldn't make the style changes to work in li-elements, so I applied the class on the anchors instead.

Css:

```
.tab1 {position:relative; overflow:hidden; }
.tab1 li { display:inline-block; margin-right:10px;} 
.tab1 li.m1 a { display:block; background:red; width:100px; height:100px;  text-align:center; color:#fff; }
.tab1 li.m1 a.on { background:pink;}
.tab1 li.m2 a { display:block; background:blue; width:100px; height:100px;  text-align:center; color:#fff; }
.tab1 li.m2 a.on { background:skyblue;}
.tab1 li.m3 a { display:block; background:green; width:100px; height:100px;  text-align:center; color:#fff; }
.tab1 li.m3 a.on { background:lightgreen;}
```

All the state changes are controlled by events in jQuery:

```
$('.tab1 li a').on('click', function(e){           
    if (!$(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        // Unselect others
        $('.tab1 li a').removeClass("selected");
        // Store the selected item, with a class
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $('.tab1 li a').mouseleave(); // Update fade out the others
        $(this).addClass("on", 300); // 300 milliseconds  
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});  

$('.tab1 li a').on('mouseover', function(e){
        $(this).addClass("on", 300);  // 300 milliseconds  
}); 

$('.tab1 li a').on('mouseleave', function(e){
        if (!$(this).hasClass("selected"))
            $(this).removeClass("on", 300);  // 300 milliseconds  
});
```

Fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/9L7Dh/3/

**Updated:**
http://fiddle.jshell.net/9L7Dh/4/

This ofcourse applies only if you are using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: Realized the items were meant to be togglable on click too? So I updated the answer a bit.